# how to export visio external data to excel

Tags: vba, excel, export, visio

I have an old VISIO file with external data on it. The source file of the data does not exist anymore.
I have tried to copy and paste the data from visio to excel with no success.

Then I tried to access the data through VBA and I don't understand the results I get:
(The amount of rows is currect, yet the data is sometimes good and sometimes not)

```
Sub test()
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim r As Variant
    Dim a() As Variant
    Dim rowSTR As String
    Dim vsoDataRecordset As Visio.DataRecordset
    For i = 1 To Visio.ActiveDocument.DataRecordsets.Count
        rowSTR = ""
        a = Visio.ActiveDocument.DataRecordsets(i).GetRowData(1)
        For j = 0 To UBound(a) - 1
            rowSTR = rowSTR & vbTab & a(j)
        Next j
        Debug.Print i & ")" & rowSTR
    Next i
End Sub
```

Do you know how to get this data from visio to excel?

Thanks
Asaf

Update: Added the source and code output: I rechecked and have no clue where the data comes from...
[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with the data is correct and sometimes not? What is incorrect about the data sometimes?

Comment: Added screenshots - I believe my code is referencing the wrong place - only even rows have data and it reminds the original but nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

This post is old but I ran into the same problem and have a solution. In your posted code, you're referencing each `DataRecordSet` and grabbing the first row, instead of finding the correct one and grabbing all rows.

We also have to avoid using `i` to count from 0 to `ExternalData.Count`; the Row IDs can skip numbers, so you have to use the real IDs from the correct `DataRecordset`.

The following code is not exactly pretty but it works. Note that the `linked` boolean is not truly part of the data set; it is, however, equivalent to the "chain" icon in the External Data window.

This was written for Visio 2013, but I believe it will work for other versions as well. After running this, you can import the file into Excel using `%` as the delimiter.

```
    Sub WriteDataSourceToFile()

    ' REQUIRES: Microsoft Scripting Runtime (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll)

    ' Below we'll intentionally cause array length errors to test each Row
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Use this to put the drawing name in the first column of each row
    Dim DrawingLabel As String
    DrawingLabel = "DRAWING_NAME_HERE"

    ' Used for getting the External Data from a specific window
    Dim PagObj As Visio.Page
    Dim vsoDataRecordset As Visio.DataRecordset

    ' Used for grabbing all shapes with a link to the current Row
    Dim shapeIDs() As Long
    Dim testLong As Long

    ' Currently only using the above as a test (linked or not linked)
    Dim linked As Boolean

    ' Stores all Row IDs from the DataRecordset and loops through each
    Dim dataRowIDs() As Long
    Dim dataRowID As Variant

    ' Stores the actual Row information and appends to rowSTR for the delimited line
    Dim rowData() As Variant
    Dim rowDataInt As Integer
    Dim rowSTR As String

    ' Used for text file output
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    ' Create a TextStream and point it at a unique filename (based on the active document)
    Dim stream As TextStream
    Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Public\Documents\GEN_" & ActiveDocument.Name & ".txt", True)

    ' Look through each window and find External Data (matches 2044)
    For Each win In Visio.ActiveWindow.Windows
        If win.ID = 2044 Then
            Set vsoDataRecordset = win.SelectedDataRecordset
            Exit For
        End If
    Next win

    ' Get each Row ID from the DataRecordSet
    dataRowIDs = vsoDataRecordset.GetDataRowIDs("")

    ' Use each Row ID as a reference
    For Each dataRowID In dataRowIDs
        linked = False

        ' Look through all pages and attempt to get Shape IDs linked to the active Row
        For Each PagObj In ActiveDocument.Pages
            PagObj.GetShapesLinkedToDataRow vsoDataRecordset.ID, dataRowID, shapeIDs

            ' Attempting to reference a 0-length array will throw an error here
            testLong = UBound(shapeIDs)
            If Err.Number Then
                Err.Clear
            Else
                ' If it didn't throw an error referencing the array, there's at least one linked shape
                linked = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next PagObj

        ' Build the output
        rowSTR = linked

        ' Get the array of Row Data
        rowData = vsoDataRecordset.GetRowData(dataRowID)

        ' Go through each column and append the value to the output string
        For rowDataInt = 0 To UBound(rowData)
            ' Using % as a delimeter to prevent text with commas causing a separated column
            rowSTR = rowSTR & "%" & rowData(rowDataInt)
        Next rowDataInt

        'Output the string to the file, putting the label at the beggining of the row
        stream.WriteLine DrawingLabel & "%" & rowSTR
    Next dataRowID

    stream.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A minor update.

' Used for text file output
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fa = fso.createtextfile("C:(a location)\output.txt", True)

And I commented out the following DIM and SET and then changed the object name from FSO.writeline to FA.writeline at the end.